# adding data to CoreData takes lot time

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

// code to add core data. have 2000 contacts to add. but adding 2000 data takes 45 secs.

```
func addData(contacts: [CNContact]) {
    for data in contacts {
         let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context)
        let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        newUser.setValue(data.identifier, forKey: "contactIdentifier")
        newUser.setValue(data.familyName, forKey: "finalName")
        newUser.setValue(data.givenName, forKey: "givenName")
        newUser.setValue(data.phoneNumbers.first?.value.value(forKey: "stringValue") as? String ?? "", forKey: "phoneNumber")
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            UIUtility.showErrorAlert("", message: Constants.errorMessage)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding in small batches. Instead of doing all 2000 at once or one-by-one, add ~50 then save your context, then do the next 50, etc. Also, you can just create the context & entity etc once outside of your for-in loop.

Comment: Also, there are already solutions to this problem posted on StackOverflow, so do a search for Core Data questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First move this line to before the loop since you only need to do it once

```
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Then replace the next two lines with

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName entityName, into: context)
```

So the start of the function should look like this

```
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
for data in contacts {
    let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName entityName, into: context)
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating `context` and `entity` once (a bit more efficient) and saving the `context` once (much more efficient) is certainly faster.

```
func addData(contacts: [CNContact]) {
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context)!
    for data in contacts {
        let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
        newUser.setValue(data.identifier, forKey: "contactIdentifier")
        newUser.setValue(data.familyName, forKey: "finalName")
        newUser.setValue(data.givenName, forKey: "givenName")
        newUser.setValue(data.phoneNumbers.first?.value.value(forKey: "stringValue") as? String ?? "", forKey: "phoneNumber")
    }
    do {
       try context.save()
    } catch {
       UIUtility.showErrorAlert("", message: Constants.errorMessage)
    }
}
```